# Use variable as ID and get table from mysql (edited)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a multiple select option form to get a table of venues. Each venue has an ID and this is what I used:

```
<?php
require("db_access.php");

if(isset($_POST['select3'])) 
{
  $aVenues = $_POST['select3'];

  if(!isset($aVenues))
  {
    echo("<p>You didn't select any venues!</p>\n");
  }
  else
  {
    $nVenues = count($aVenues);

    echo("<p>You selected $nVenues venues: ");
    for($i=0; $i < $nVenues; $i++)
    {
      echo($aVenues[$i] . " ");
    }
    echo("</p>");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id IN (" . implode(",",$aVenues) . ")";
$comma_separated = implode(",", $aVenues);
echo $comma_separated;



  }
}

?>
```

It results in this:
[image]

However I thought that the code would use those two numbers below and draw out a table with those id's I used :/ ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array` is used in `implode(",", $array);` but is not defined anywhere else that we can see.  It is perhaps intended to be:

```
implode(",", $aVenues);
```

**UPDATE**

Per comments, it does not draw a table because you never actually query your database.

You build your SQL statement, but you need to execute it and fetch the result set.

```
// Make sure you actually have a database connection
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id IN (" . implode(",",$aVenues) . ")";
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
echo $comma_separated;

// Execute query and fetch result rowset
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
  $rowset = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rowset[] = $row;
  }
  var_dump($rowset);
}
else echo mysql_error();
```

Comment: Cool, the error is gone now, however it now displays "2, 6" under what I had originally but does not draw a table and use those numbers as IDs :/

Comment: @pufAmuf Because you never executed your query and fetched its result set. See addition above.

Comment: Weird, why do you think I might be getting a password error?
Access denied for user 'nightl7'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: <?
$username="nightl7_main";
$password="my_password";
$database="nightl7_nightlife";
?>
I use this code on all other tables and it works :/

Comment: Could it be that I am including this php code in the middle of the page along with the rest of the html on this form?

Comment: @pufAmuf If that's the full contents of `db_access.php`, you never established a connection with `mysql_connect()` either and your script is using default database credentials.  Call `mysql_connect()` after including `db_access.php`.

Comment: Ahhh Great Michael :) Can I use what they do on this tutorial http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlselect.php to create a table like that? Your code works amazingly, jut that it creates a huge dump of information that I would like to sort into a table :) 
http://i.imgur.com/2OXD3.png

Comment: What I meant to say was that what exactly could I replace in there with the 'td echo some_column' so that I could create a table like that  :)

Comment: @pufAmuf Yes you can do what that tutorial suggests and replace the `$row['name']` etc. with your own column names.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael :))) So I should replace `var_dump($rowset);` with that table script and change `while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))` to `while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rowset ))` ? :)

Comment: @pufAmuf Remove the `var_dump($rowset)` entirely and replace the whole `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` with the table script you found.

Comment: Sorry Michael, I thought you had gone offline so I tried to do it on my own and failed. You are the best!